# What do the arrows at the left side of the SE app mean?

Tags: support, android-app

What do arrows to the left of the questions mean?

[image]

Comment: You mean the arrows to the *left*?

Comment: @animuson having problems with orientation )))

Comment: @Mat they don't want to be tapped, otherwise i wouldn't ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They mean the net number of votes: upvotes - downvotes.

On the desktop site frontpage, to the left of every question you see: "x votes, y answers, z views". The mobile app has less screen room to play with, so it does not display views and replaces the words "votes" and "answers" with icons.

The icon replacing the word "votes" is an up arrow, even though the question score may be negative. I imagine the designers could have considered using down arrow for negatively scored questions, but on the other hand "-10 down" would be a confusing *double negative* statement.

Comment: A! Understood. Thought it has some action. Thanks!